# Getting Specific Link Section VB

Tags: vb.net

In this link `https://?code=[CODE]&scope=[scope]`

I want to be able to pull just the `[CODE]` out of the link and save it in My.Settings.AccessToken

So I can later enter it into another link later that needs the token.

`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/amtraxtge/subscriptions?oauth_token=[CODE]`

Any basic idea will help it doesn't just have to be for the code above.

Comment: OAuth generally tokens expire and are not reusable

Answer (score 3):

My VB.Net is a bit rusty, but this should work using the [`Uri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Uri(v=vs.100).aspx) class and [`HttpUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx):

```
Dim uri As new Uri("https://?code=[CODE]&scope=[scope]")
Dim code as String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("code")
```

Comment: Its coming in as `'HttpUtlity' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level` and I cannot import anything.

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to `System.Web.dll`